# worker exits after starting in Supervisor

Tags: elixir, gen-server, erlang-supervisor

I am trying to start the below workers in a Supervisor that I am calling in application module in mix.exs

Like this

```
defmodule AppStarter do
import Supervisor.Spec
def start(_type,_args) do
    children=[
        worker(TPMod1,[],[]),
        worker(TPMod2,[],[])
    ]
    opts=[strategy: :one_for_one, name: HelloVisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children,opts)
end


end
```

One of my module is GenServer and another I kept a simple listening process.

```
defmodule TPMod1 do

def start_link() do
 IO.puts "started TPMod1"
 listen()
end



def listen() do
  receive do
    _ -> :ok
  end
  listen()
end

 def child_spec(opts) do
      %{
        id: __MODULE__,
        start: {__MODULE__, :start_link, []},
        type: :worker,
        restart: :permanent,
        shutdown: 500
      }
    end


end
```

Problem is it get stuck and doesn't start the worker 2 `TPMod2` I tried doing in `TPMod1`'s `start_link()`

```
def start_link() do
 IO.puts "started TPMod1"
 Task.async(&listen/0)
end
```

But that give me this

> ** (Mix) Could not start application tproject: AppStarter.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to
>   start child: TPMod1
>       ** (EXIT) %Task{owner: #PID<0.143.0>, pid: #PID<0.144.0>, ref: #Reference<0.2187290957.3420192769.212288>}

I can make it GenServer and make it work but how can we start a simple worker? And why supervisor is not restarting it again? not infinitly but some times? It should have at least tried restarting and fail. Please suggest other improvements too if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supervisor expects the children to return `{:ok, pid}`, `:ignore` or `{:error, reason}`.

It hangs because when the supervisor runs the `start_link` function on your worker, it executes (as himself), `listen` which sets a `receive` block, so it gets stuck there. When you use the gen_* module's `start_link` and friends, it takes care of spawning, returning correctly etc.

In your case you could switch:

```
def start_link() do
 IO.puts "started TPMod1"
 listen()
end
```

to:

```
def start_link() do
 pid = spawn(__MODULE__, :listen, [])
 {:ok, pid}
end
```

And this should do it.

Comment: Cool! So is it good practice to always use gen_* instead of doing simple spawn and return?

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari I think in 99% of regular cases there's really no reasons to not use an existing OTP behaviour, since it satisfies the expectations of supervisors etc, while with raw processes you have to implement those if you want it to be OTP. Sometimes a gen_server is too much (but any process  that has a bit of structure fits well) and you can use something like Tasks which (through different modes, like async_nolink, etc) fit well inside other OTP behaviours such as gen_servers and can be spawned from inside them, or from the outside be waited, etc. It all depends of course...

Comment: Cool! So is it good practice to always use *gen_\* [behaviors] instead of doing simple spawn and return?* -- It's not just good practice--it's the only practice.  At one time, I tried to figure out how to use a Supervisor to start an arbitrary process, and it took a lot of digging around in erlang to finally figure out that you can't use a Supervisor to start an arbitrary process. A Supervisor expects that the processes it starts are OTP `Applications`, ...

Comment: ....which means that the workers have to define certain functions, and those functions have to return certain values that the Supervisor is expecting...That is how a Supervisor is able to communicate with the worker.  Here's some more info: https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/supervisor-and-application.html

Comment: Also: `Supervisor.Spec --This module is deprecated. Use the new child specifications outlined in the Supervisor module instead.`  [Supervisor module](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html)

Comment: @7stud That was super helpful for clarity.. saved a lot of time thanks alot